# Correct way to align equations equal to zero

Tags: notation

This is a question related to formatting. I have an expression that is equal to zero; I work over this expression to obtain a final relation as shown below:

$$\begin{align*}
0 & =\int_{V}\nabla\cdot\mathbf{A}\,\mathrm{d}V\\
 & =\int_{S}\mathbf{A}\cdot d\mathbf{S}\\
 & =\int_{S}\mathbf{\hat{n}}\cdot\mathbf{A}\,d\mathit{S}\\
 & =\left(\mathbf{A}_{i}-\mathbf{A}_{e}\right)\cdot\mathbf{\hat{n}}
\end{align*}$$

My question is: is it correct formatting to leave the zero in the left hand side? I have searched for answers but I could not find it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I see nothing wrong with that.

Comment: I've seen many such calculations. The only other way to format it that would look natural to me would be to reverse the entire calculation, starting with $\left(\mathbf{A}_{i}-\mathbf{A}_{e}\right)\cdot\mathbf{\hat{n}}$ and concluding with $0$. But if the natural flow of your argument in its context runs the direction you've shown, there is nothing wrong with it.

Comment: That looks correct to me, but... I feel like this question should be on Meta instead. On the other hand, the notation tag description does mention usage...

Comment: Thanks for your responses! This was very helful !